# How to give a unique "id" for each canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Canvas is new to me - so I need help.

I have a function that draws data retrieved using getImageData () - on an existing canvas or newly created.

I need to make it possible for a newly created canvas to give it a unique id. However, when I try the following - the canvas is created but the id is undefined.

```
function drawImageData(img, t1, t2, cc, scale, targetCanvas, userId) {
var canvas = targetCanvas || document.createElement('canvas');
if(!targetCanvas){
    canvas.setAttribute('id', userId); 

   // the rest of the code
   }
```

How to properly assign userId - to "id" canvas?

Comment: Can we see an example how you are calling this function? Are you sure you're passing `userId` ?

Comment: the js seems correct, are you sure that userId is correctly passed?

Comment: I do not know how it works, but it works now ;) Thank you for your interest in my problem

Comment: @blueberry Not sure what you meant by *I need to make it possible for a newly created canvas to give it a unique id*, which is what I was trying to help with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - As per OP, his problem got resolved without changing his/her code, so this question doesn't offer any solution to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine.

[image]

jsfiddle.net/qsekzt9x/

@gurvinder372 is right about the if condition in his answer below